# Linq to entity update query not updating the table

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Its just a simple Linq to Entity update query i tried with the following code but it doesn't update the "User" column in the DB.

Its not even throwing any exception also,please some one point me what am missing here.

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities ();

var query = from SEVTs in db.SEVTs
            where SESID == "4747747"
            select SEVTs;

foreach (var SEVTs in query) {
  SEVTs.USER = "Test";
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Quite interesting, when i try the follwing query in the sql server its not update the record

```
update Schedwin.SEVT  
set
USER3='Test'
Where
SESID='4747747' // here i pass the value as a string
```

SESID data type is CHAR and its a primary key. if i pass the value as SESID=4747747 then it update that record.

Please ignore my question.

Here what i missed my input value SESID == "4747747" //this have whitespace that's why it didn't updated that particular record.

Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nor modifying `SEVTs.USER`, but some local variable.

(BTW: create a context in a `using` construct)

Comment: ,thanks for that comment,my bad i forgot to include SEVTs.User="test" in the code above, updated my question,sorry.I will definitely going to use "using".Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then it is very likely that it updates a different database than the one you're looking at.

Comment: Here what i missed, my input value SESID == "4747747" //this have whitespace that's why it didn't updated that particular record.